# Getting State.Push is not a function after adding Redux-Persist

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I've developing Todo app with react-typescript and redux. I've test the app without the redux-persist and it's shows list of added task, but when I add redux-persist it won't dispatch store and has an error of  **State.push is not a function**.

**Redux Store**

```
    import { persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
    import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
    
    const persistConfig = {
      key: "root",
      storage,
      whitelist: ["Todo"],
    };
    
    const persistor = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);
    
    export const store = configureStore({
      reducer: persistor,
      middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({ serializableCheck: false }),
    });

**Slice Reducer**

interface IinitialState {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  dateAdded: any;
  completed: boolean;
}

const initialState: IinitialState[] = [];

const dataSlice = createSlice({
  name: "Todo",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addTodos: {
      reducer: (state, action: PayloadAction<IinitialState>) => {
        state.push(action.payload);
        return state;
      },
      prepare: (title: string, description: string) => ({
        payload: {
          id: uuidv4(),
          title,
          description,
          dateAdded: new Date().getTime(),
          completed: false,
        } as IinitialState,
      }),
    },
   },
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry been dumb, My model was wrong so it was read as object not array, I fixed it by re-model my interface.

```
interface IinitialState {
todo: Array<Todo>;
}
interface Todo {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  dateAdded: any;
  completed: boolean;
}
const initialState: IinitialState = {
  todo: [],
};
```